Trying to wordwrap and item in a QListWidget
Ive been trying to wrap the text in an item box in a QListWidget. My program is To Do application.
I see the context i added might not be enough so here is the github repo: https://github.com/NordinCoding/ToDoList
Im also pretty new to using github so if any jankiness is noticed id love some tips
It takes text from a .txt file and uses that to populate the list widget:
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

QFile file(path);

if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
}

ui->listWidget_1->setWordWrap(true);
ui->listWidget_1->setStyleSheet("QListView QLineEdit{background:#FFF2D7; 
color:black;}");

QTextStream in(&file);

while(!in.atEnd()) {
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(in.readLine(), ui->listWidget_1);
    if(item->checkState())
    {
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
    }
    else
    {
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    }

    item->setForeground(QBrush(Qt::black));

    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
    ui->listWidget_1->addItem(item);

}

file.close();
}

The only problem is when the text is too long it creates a horizontal scrollbar and doesnt wrap the text but i want it to wrap. I am aware my if(item->checkState()) currently does nothing but its just there because i want to do something with it someday. Does anyone know how to make it so that the items actually wrap? I read alot about delegates and paint() but i cant seem to figure out how to apply it to my function.

Word wrapping will only happen if the item has enough space to show more lines (as the documentation explains. You should create an item delegate that overrides sizeHint() and returns an appropriate height. Note that the if(item->checkState()) block is pointless, as it is calling addItem() if the parent argument is added to the QListWidgetItem constructor.

@musicamante: I am 95% certain an item always has space to grow to multiple lines (at the cost of having a vertical scrollbar instead of the horizontal one) in QListWidgets and it will do so automatically by default (contrary to QTableView/QTreeView). No need to resort to delegate shenanigans for that. If the items truly do not grow automatically for OP, it is either cause by a version change somewhere (that I cannot reproduce) or by external code (e.g. a property being set in the ui file).

I have posted an answer for demonstration; since QListWidget is well-behaved in regard to word wrap and I do not see anything in your code that could explain the behavior you describe, I will vote your question as Not reproducible. Feel free to edit your question to include more details and help us do our analysis.

@Atmo You're right. I was confused by another related question I remembered which was asking for custom wrapping.

Items in QListWidgets actually grow automatically when you activate word wrap, which you did.
Below is a demonstration:
#include <QtWidgets/QListWidget>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QListWidget l;
    l.setWordWrap(true);
    QString words = QString::fromWCharArray(L"ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; ++i) {
        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(words.left(i + 1 + i / 3), &l);
        item->setCheckState(i & 1 ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
        l.addItem(item);
    }
    l.show();

    return a.exec();
}

And it results, like I said, in:

If you pay close attention to the animated gif, you may notice some words actually do not wrap around to the next line.
The clue is hidden in my call to QString::fromWCharArray: the first few space from the string I reuse are actually no-break spaces instead of regular spaces, and the widget behaves accordingly by not breaking the line on no-break spaces.
Regarding your problem, either your file contains such no-break spaces (you need to make sure that is not the case if you do not expect them) or you are doing something in another place of your code (incl. ui file) that overrides the default behavior of QListWidget.

Edit: As it turns out, fixing the list item height is a bad idea for word wrap: the complete source code contained #listWidget_1::item { height: 30px; }, which prevents items from growing in heights.
BTW, you must also make sure the widgets themselves follow the geometry of your window by adding them to a layout, which did not appear to be the case.

Uhm, it seems that the no-break spaces were not preserved in the example.

Arrhhhh if the markdown or the HTML does not preserve them, then you/OP'll have to take my word for it.

I do believe you :-) Yet, maybe you could sub/replace that line with appropriate chars, so that it may become actually reproducible.

I cant seem to get it to work however i have added the entire source code to my github repo here: https://github.com/NordinCoding/ToDoList if youre interested i would love if you could take a look at it to see what i might be doing wrong

Man, you wrote #listWidget_1::item { height: 30px; in your stylesheet.... Items can't allow word wrap if you do not allow them to grow in height, can they?

actually only portable way to include special characters into code is to use their hex codes (or mnemonics, like end-of-line one). Compiler and ide might skip them too otherwise. It also leads to interesting code frauds when Unicodeis used to make code look not like what it would be compiled as (a number of malicious examples on GitHub were encountered)

In edit mode, the cell editor appears to be QLineEdit, which places the text on one line. A delegate was proposed above - here is one possible implementation:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QItemDelegate>

class Delegate:public QItemDelegate
{
public:
    using QItemDelegate::QItemDelegate;

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                          const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        return new QTextEdit(parent);
    }
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        if(auto edit=dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(editor)){
            model->setData(index, QVariant(edit->toPlainText()));
        }
    }
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        if(auto edit=dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(editor)){
            edit->setPlainText(index.data().toString());
        }
    }
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
                              const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QListWidget l;
    l.show();
    l.setItemDelegate(new Delegate);
    l.setWordWrap(true);
    QString lorem=
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris rhoncus felis mauris, ut semper lectus sagittis aliquet. Duis et purus ac tellus imperdiet mattis ac nec metus. Etiam iaculis tortor ante, et fringilla massa fringilla quis.";

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(lorem);
        item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        l.addItem(item);
    }

    return a.exec();
}

Of course you can use QPlainTextEdit, as I was correctly pointed out in the comments:
class Delegate:public QItemDelegate
{
public:
    using QItemDelegate::QItemDelegate;

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                          const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        return new QPlainTextEdit(parent);
    }
};

I suggest using the delegate solely to get multi-line text in cell edit mode.(Which probably doesn't quite correspond to the question...)
my option:

Gif with filling like a Atmo:


Unless the OP didn't explain themselves appropriately (which should eventually be clarified in a comment to the question before answering), the issue is not about the editor, but how items are displayed. Besides: 1. if only plain text is being used, QPlainTextEdit should be preferred, which shouldn't need setModelData() or setEditorData() overrides (and updateEditorGeometry() is implied). Also, answers are sorted based on user preference (see the right aligned combo box at the beginning of the answer section).

musicamante, thanks for the tip about sorting answers! I wasn't paying attention. You are right about QPlainTextEdit, I just wanted to show the author of the topic the approximate mechanism of how the delegate works.
